# mysql unable to start service in my localhost

Tags: mysql

when i start mysql service that shows bellow error.

```
"Could not start the MySql service on local Computer
Error 1067: The process terminited unexpectedly"
```

when i check  error logs it shows bellow error

```
130704 12:58:44 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
130704 12:58:44  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 47.0M
130704 12:58:44  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool InnoDB: Error: log file .\ib_logfile0 is of different size 0 25165824 bytes InnoDB: than specified in the .cnf file 0 20971520 bytes!    
130704 12:58:44 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
130704 12:58:44 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
130704 12:58:44 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported table type: INNODB
130704 12:58:44 [ERROR] Aborting
130704 12:58:44 [Note] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin\mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

Help me to resolve this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I googled and found this problem in the mysql page. It may help you.

try this answers: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?22,144428,249656#msg-249656

actually the next answer from Richard Lee may help more.
http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?22,144428,250105#msg-250105

Comment: I just delete my.ini file and run MySQLInstanceConfig file then mysql is working fine

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, had added some changes to `my.cnf` as `query_cache_limit = 2M, query_cache_size = 64M, join_buffer_size = 4M, thread_cache_size = 80, table_cache = 264, innodb_buffer_pool_size = 2400M`, here in my bank and stopped, I returned the original file with the only change `innodb_buffer_pool_size = 2400M`. Give worked.

Answer (score -1):

I just delete my.ini file and run MySQLInstanceConfig file then mysql is working fine